# Is there a way to relay information from a command block to the server console?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have a program I coded that can control and read the server console, and I need a way to get information to appear in the server console without players seeing it. Is there a command that a command block can use that will do this? I have tried using the /say command, but everyone else can see that. If there isn't a command that will do this, is it possible to program a plugin to relay this using a command block?

Comment: What kind of feedback do you want? The best I got was making the gamerule "sendCommandFeedback" to false and "commandBlockOutput" set to true and doing a command [/scoreboard players set @p dummy 1] so it outputs [@: Set [dummy] for Player to 1].

Comment: The feedback I need are basically commands that the program reading the console will interpret. I could use feedback in the form of a number, having each number represent a command, but if it's possible I would rather have text.

Comment: You can use the command /tag instead of the scoreboard one and use an armorstand instead of a player. The problem you may find is that you need to remove the tag you added for everytime you want it to appear on the console (If a tag isn't successfully added or removed, it won't have feedback)